# Tersest way of increasing CSS selector' class-level specificity without altering selector scope

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity, oocss

I'm currently elaborating a variation on [Nicole Sullivan's OOCSS grids module](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/Grids) that only requires a single container class to determine the layout of immediate descendants. I'm aware this bears the caveats of only working in CSS3 supporting browsers.

Here's an example of the difference:

Vanilla [OOCSS grids](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/7Bd8V/) rule:

```
.unit1of4 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

My [reduced grids](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/32Q8B/) rule:

```
.line > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
.line > :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
.line > :nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2) {
    width:25%;
}
```

Another significant caveat is the assumption that an element's fractional size is determined exclusively by its number of siblings — whereas that's the essential point of this code (to enable leaner HTML without explicit sizes all over the place), there will be exceptions where one might wish to have disproportionate widths.

Because of the specificity of my selectors, I can't simply stick the OOCSS module back in: specifying a `unitXofY` class in the HTML would be done specifically to supersede the default assumption, but in practice my selectors are stronger and would always override the specified class.

What I'm looking for is the tersest or most elegant way to supersede these selectors *without limiting the practical effect of the specificity*. That is to say, it must not make any assumptions about the selected element other than its class that will not always be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can come up with is `:nth-child(n)`, in that it resolves to a meaningless statement which translates into plain English as 'a child element', which will always be the case of nested fractions. The code to implement this looks like this:

```
.line > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),
.line > :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3),
.line > :nth-child(3):nth-last-child(2),
.size1of4:nth-child(n):nth-child(n):nth-child(n) {
    width:25%;
}
```

The selector is specified 3 times over such that it trumps the previous selectors by 1, meaning it can also trump the next rule governing `.size1of5`.

As a SASS mixin:

Because this is a verbose hack, [I've packaged it up as a SASS mixin](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/9959522):

```
@mixin increase-specificity( $depth: 1 ) {
    $sel : '';

    @while($depth > 0) {
        $sel   : $sel + ':nth-child(n)';
        $depth : $depth - 1;
    }

    &#{$sel} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the class-name as many times as you like to increase specificity, as long as there's no space between the repetitions of `.className`, it's assumed to apply to the same element.  According to the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity), "Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity"

So you could, for example, use:

```
.size1of4.size1of4.size1of4.size1of4{/*some styles*/}
```

...and this will apply to any element with just `size1of4` in the class attribute, overiding another declaration with only 3 class-names or pseudo-classes in its selector.

Comment: The problem is that `.size1of4.size1of4.size1of4.size1of4` still requires an element to have that classname to be selected. As far as I can work out, `:nth-child(n)` is the tersest selector that would effect any element (ie, any conceivable element conforms to it).

Comment: I understand that point, but what's confusing is that *your own answer* also is using a specific class-name. I'm just saying  that if you specify a classname at least once (as you have: `.size1of4`), you can specify it as many additional times as you  like without being any less general.

Comment: Right, I see your point – your method is essentially to take whatever the selector was in the first place, and just repeat as necessary. I guess it comes down to preference for a generic pattern that can't be confused with specifics. But then I can also imagine somebody grokking your method far quicker (rather than sitting there trying to work out what all those `:nth-child` selectors are actually doing).

Comment: Perhaps, though either solution is kind of *advanced territory*.